# Pass Objects in FormData with angular 12 to .net core api

Tags: .net, angular, api, .net-core, angular12

I am working with angular 12 and .Net Core api

here is my object which i create dynamically

[image]

I wanted to pass this dynamic object to .net api but it does not works with Form Data as i tried to do it.

As you can see **Value** is dynamic sometime it will be a file and sometime it will be a string how can i do it?

I tried to do it like this

```
  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append('Items', JSON.stringify(payload));
```

but i get nothing for file string is working.
Like this

```
    [HttpPost, Route("create")]
    public ResponseResult CreateNewCertificate(IFormCollection data)
    {
        ResponseResult apiRtn = new ResponseResult();
        try
        {
            if (data.TryGetValue("Items", out var someData))
            {
            }
            apiRtn.Status = true;
            apiRtn.Message = "Success";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            apiRtn.Message = ex.Message;
            apiRtn.Status = false;
        }
        return apiRtn;
    }
```

i got the data in someData variable but file object is empty "{}".

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see Value is dynamic sometime it will be a file and sometime it will be a string how can i do it?

That's your mistake right here - it's a bad design to allow the properties of your object to be anything they want.

I suggest extracting the file to a separate nullable variable - your job will become much easier. And the other developers will not get confused due to getting a **FILE** where they expected a string.